# On an AVL tree insertion/deletion, which nodes have their height changed and why?

Tags: data-structures

I've begun learning about AVL trees. It seems that the assertion with this data structure is that with every insertion/deletion, the only nodes whose height changes are nodes on the path towards the root (from the inserted/deleted node). How exactly is this 'proved'? I've gone through many examples and it would appear to hold true, but I haven't seen a convincing proof/explanation from any of the texts I have read.

Comment: Try proving it by induction (formulate an inductive predicate, then trying to prove it holds for the recursive implementation of the insert procedure).  Give that a try, then if you're still stuck, edit your question to show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Is there really anything to prove here? If no node is added to a subtree, then its height will not change, is it?

Comment: If in algorithm description there is stated that after insertion (after traversing down to insertion point, and inserting) you go up *on the path traversed* and nowhere else, is there really need to prove that it doesn't change height of nodes it didn't touched (you do not insert anything or delete anything in other subtrees)?